# How to execute UFT scripts through AOM Framework?

Tags: hp-uft

I have Five Automated Script and want to execute overnight. Can anyone let me know how to execute it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can schedule those tasks using task scheduler using Application Object Model(AOM).
There are many ways, one approach you can use am writing below: 
Create a vbs file and trigger it using Windows scheduler.  You can write code to pick up your execution scripts in UFT. Refer below code for your reference.

```
    Set obj = CreateObject("Quicktest.Application")
'// Set AOM file and test script path
obj.Visible = True 
obj.Launch
obj.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnError"
obj.Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"
obj.Options.Run.ViewResults = False

obj.Open path     '----"path of your script"
        obj.Test.Run qtpResults,True
        VarStatus =obj.Test.LastRunResults.Status
obj.Test.Close
```

Let me know if you need any other help. Happy to help :-)